# Bitrix не работает шаблон

Tags: php, битрикс

[image: Картинка]

Добрый вечер, возникла проблема, установил битрикс, создал новый шаблон, далее прописываю стандартный php! Но при сохранении белый экран, если php закоментить то шаблон нормально работает всё отлично, но если разкоментить какой нибудь кусочек кода то белый экран! НИкто незнает в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: вы уверены что стандартный пхп начинается именно с `<?` ?

Comment: Уверен какая разница?

Comment: Включи отображение ошибок, сразу увидишь в чем проблема.

Comment: Причин, на вскидку, я как минимум 6 могу сказать, но Вам правильно @u_mulder написал: включите вывод ошибок php и все станет намного яснее. Может вы к шаблону напрямую обращаетесь, может ядро битрикса не подключилось, можно что в исполняющем файле не так... да всякое может быть. И не редактируйте шаблон и вообще php файлы через Битрикс. Не знаю как сейчас, но раньше Битрикс мог поломать файл координально. Пользуйтесь хоть "блокнотом" через фтп, но не битрикс-редактором для исполняемых файлов.

Comment: Чтобы проверить, нужен полный код файла. Ошибка может быть дальше по коду